# Taking input from a user per element in a SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-list

I ran into problems when making a SwiftUI List of views to take a number value from a user.

Each element in the list was a view that represents a question struct and was supposed to take an int value back. First I tried having the value directly on the view struct as the question structs are obviously not supposed to contain any answers themselves. The plan was to combine the answers from the views with their question's id and a timestamp and store away somewhere else.

```
struct QuestionRow: View {
    var question: Question
    @State var trueRating: Int = -1
    @State var displayedRating: Int = -1
```

This failed because SwiftUI's List generates and discards the views on the fly as the enter and leave the screen (or at least i think that was the issue, Apple's documentation on this seems sparse). Thus destroying my data as the user goes through the list.

The solution to this seemed to be to introduce a struct for the answers (which i was going to eventually anyway). The user would interact with the view, which would save the data into the new struct; even if the list unloaded the data would be preserved.

```
struct AnswerRow: View {
    var answer: Answer
```

This lead my straight to

`Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`

Because of course it did. Can't modify a member of a view struct outside a function marked "mutating" which the view structs body declaration isn't.

I can think of two workarounds:

1. Make a wrapper function inside the view struct

```
mutating func SetScoreWrapper(score: Int) {
        self.answer.SetScore(newScore: score)
    }
```

2. Turn my struct into a class?

Something tells me there is a much better way to solve this.
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many questions and you want to preserve the state of the questions, then you could use a `Vstack` with a `ForEach` to build each `QuestionRow`. Note that this will cause them to all be loaded into memory when the view appears, so it's not a good choice if you have hundreds of rows.

If you want to stick with `List`, then try creating an `Answers` data model and make it stateful in the view with the list. Then, you can pass a binding to each `QuestionRow`, which will then update the source of truth. This prevents the information from being destroyed when the row scrolls off-screen.